# Advantages of locations in the solar system for a space station

Tags: science-fiction, space-constructs

In my story, a hostile alien force has arrived in our solar system and parked a station to keep us in line.  They've mined the near-sun planets to build a Dyson Swarm, something they do fairly frequently when conquering civilizations.  The station would act, also, as the collection point of the energy collected from the swarm's drones.

Where is the best place to put this station?

Edit: I am sorry this wasn't a very good question to start with.  I didn't make it clear enough what I needed for information, so I'll try to fix it.

With the near-sun planets gone, where would the Earth-Sun LaGrange point be?  If I know distances, I can figure out the sorts of speeds I'd need for my setting's ships to be able to achieve for narratively useful transport between Earth and the Station.

Comment: Best is a subjective metric, dependent upon how tradeoffs are valued. It's highly likely that in this context best will be related to how the energy is transported, stored, and what its intended use is, as well as where human reside within the system. Without those details we cannot attempt to meaningfully answer this question.

Comment: We're going to need more information on what 'best' means in this situation, which means that we're going to need to know more about this dyson swarm and how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately we require that edits don't invalidate existing answers. When we have people firing from the hip and answering posts that need additional work that creates a barrier to reopening the question by making edits. . As such you'll need to ask a new question to ask where the earth-sun Lagrange point would be if the near-sun planets are mined out. You'll need to clarify exactly what planets you consider near-sun planets as well as what you mean by mined our.

Comment: With your edit you are asking "where would the Lagrange point be", which is something a quick query in any search engine would return

Comment: The absence of the inner planets wouldn't affect the LaGrange points between Earth and the Sun. They are minor perturbations that just make it a little harder to keep something there.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is relative, but you've provided enough of a description to make a good recommendation.

### L1

You need somewhere that follows the Earth, so they can keep tabs on us. Since you stated that they have a near-sun Dyson swarm, the rational place to put a space station would be at the Lagrange point between the swarm and Earth. This wouldn't be close enough to spy on us with super-satellites, but they would have automated satellites for that, anyway.

Comment: thank you!  I am very new and didn't know exactly what to add!

Comment: If as OP says the near-sun planets are mined out wouldn't there no longer be earth-sun Lagrange points? Please don't answer questions where you acknowledge that there is insufficient information to answer definitively and instead make assumptions about OP's world instead of working with them to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @sphennings, Where does OP say "mined out"? Are you suggesting that "mined out" would automatically mean "mined out of existence?" I'm having a hard time imagining a world where aliens have literally stolen the Earth out from underneath us, and yet feel they have to keep an eye on us. Could you explain that, please? While you're at it, could you tell me why you feel a need to vote answers down because someone else can answer questions that happen to be beyond your personal understanding?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what OP meant. As such it's our responsibility, especially with new users, to request clarification and improve the quality of the question instead of answering it. There's an expectation that users of this site only [answer well asked questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Not%20all%20questions%20can%20or%20should%20be%20answered%20here.) If a question isn't well asked we should instead work to improve the question.

Comment: Note that because of our policy that edits should not invalidate existing answers, quickly answering a question makes it more difficult for the OP or anyone who seeks to assist them resolve the issues with the question.

Comment: "It's unclear exactly what OP meant." He asked for a geometric solution. The only thing unclear was how orbital dynamics can solve it. If you generalize the Dyson swarm as a circle centered around the Sun, and draw a line between it's center and any location for "Earth" outside of the circle, you define the optimal solution set for minimal energy cost. There's only one stable orbit that stays on that line. It's a clear question with two parameters that clearly define the solution set. I'm really baffled at your reaction.

Comment: OP isn't clear if the earth is considered an near-sun planet or not. If it is and it has been mined out then there will not be any earth sun Lagrange points. Similarly if the population of humanity is dispersed between multiple stellar bodies then saying a Lagrange point isn't a complete answer.

Comment: @sphennings, Can you identify any piece of fiction where the author felt a need to specify that Earth was full of people? Unless specified, this can always be presumed. This is common sense. Since it is common sense, I accept that it might not have occurred to you as the obvious answer. This is not an excuse for penalizing me or OP. Furthermore, he specifies that the aliens need a space station to keep us in line. This is a clear indicator that they don't have an occupying force on Earth itself, and that eliminates it from any possible list of planets mined.

Comment: The question COULD be more clear. Not being perfectly clear doesn't make it close-worthy. You can always nit-pick something to death, but that's an unhealthy habit.